# Select items with hierarchy on columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchical-data

I have a list of products. Each product has a default category (`CategoryDefaultId`). Categories are organised in a hierarchy.

Examples of categories:

| CategoryId | CategoryParentId | Designation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | Vehicles |
| 2 | NULL | MF |
| 3 | 1 | Dirt Bike |
| 4 | 1 | Pocket Bike |
| 5 | 2 | Dirt Bike |
| 6 | 2 | Pocket Bike |
| 7 | 5 | Fox 110cc |
| 8 | 5 | Fox 250cc |
| 9 | 6 | Condor 60cc |
| 10 | 7 | Engine |
| 11 | 7 | Others |
| 12 | 8 | Engine |
| 13 | 9 | Engine |

I want to display for each product, each categories, starting by the higher category.

This is the result I want to get:

| ProductId | Designation | CategoryDefaultId | Category | Category 2 | Category 3 | Category 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Prod1 | 5 | MF | Dirt Bike | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | Prod2 | 3 | Vehicles | Dirt Bike | NULL | NULL |
| 3 | Prod3 | 4 | MF | Pocket Bike | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | Prod4 | 2 | MF | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 5 | Prod5 | 13 | MF | Pocket Bike | Condor 60cc | Engine |
| 6 | Prod6 | 11 | MF | Dirt Bike | Fox 110cc | Others |

I try different ways to do it, but unfortunately, I don't get what I need.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you put your source data in the form of an actual table

Comment: Please share sample data from the table that holds this data, otherwise there is no way for us to help, besides saying: if the data is in a `child | parent` type of format, typical for hierarchical data, then a recursive CTE would be the correct route to solving.

Comment: I added the list of categories in a table. I cant put all of the datas, but I think with this examples, it's understandable.

Comment: Do you really want the result in a denormalized format? For that to be accurate you are going to need to use dynamic sql because you have no way of knowing how many categories you may have. Do a search for either `dynamic cross tab` or `dynamic pivot`. This type of question has been asked and answered hundreds of times.

Comment: Actually the categories are on 4 levels, and it will never have more. I gonna check more about dynamic cross tab and dynamic pivot.

Comment: "I try different ways to do it ...".  Where???  I don't see a way posted on the question.

Answer (score 0):

With a finite depth, you could do this with just a few self-joins:

```
DECLARE @Categories TABLE (CategoryId INT, CategoryParentId INT, Designation NVARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO @Categories (CategoryId, CategoryParentId, Designation) VALUES
(1,  NULL, 'Vehicles'), (2,  NULL, 'MF'), (3,  1, 'Dirt Bike'), (4,  1, 'Pocket Bike'), (5,  2, 'Dirt Bike'), 
(6,  2, 'Pocket Bike'), (7,  5, 'Fox 110cc'), (8,  5, 'Fox 250cc'), (9,  6, 'Condor 60cc'), (10, 7, 'Engine'), 
(11, 7, 'Others'), (12, 8, 'Engine'), (13, 9, 'Engine'); 

SELECT cp.CategoryID AS CategoryID1, cp.Designation AS Category1, 
       cp1.CategoryID AS CategoryID2, cp1.Designation AS Category2, 
       cp2.CategoryID AS CategoryID3, cp2.Designation AS Category3, 
       cp3.CategoryID AS CategoryID4, cp3.Designation AS Category4, 
       cp4.CategoryID AS CategoryID5, cp4.Designation AS Category5
  FROM @Categories cp
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Categories cp1
      ON cp.CategoryId = cp1.CategoryParentId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Categories cp2
      ON cp1.CategoryId = cp2.CategoryParentId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Categories cp3
      ON cp2.CategoryId = cp3.CategoryParentId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Categories cp4
      ON cp3.CategoryId = cp4.CategoryParentId
 WHERE cp.CategoryParentId IS NULL
```

| CategoryID1 | Category1 | CategoryID2 | Category2 | CategoryID3 | Category3 | CategoryID4 | Category4 | CategoryID5 | Category5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Vehicles | 3 | Dirt Bike |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | Vehicles | 4 | Pocket Bike |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | MF | 5 | Dirt Bike | 7 | Fox 110cc | 10 | Engine |  |  |
| 2 | MF | 5 | Dirt Bike | 7 | Fox 110cc | 11 | Others |  |  |
| 2 | MF | 5 | Dirt Bike | 8 | Fox 250cc | 12 | Engine |  |  |
| 2 | MF | 6 | Pocket Bike | 9 | Condor 60cc | 13 | Engine |  |  |